# How to connect Bluetooth 4.0 / Smart / Low energy device with Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to write the C# application which receives some date from BLE device and then writes the data to the file. I've found example [here](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Category:HealthDemo) but it doesn't work on my computer. 1st of all it says "Failed COM Port Open". actually `SerialPort.GetPortNames();` returns null.
when I use Scan on Setup tabpage it fails to find any device. So I don't understand how to connect them.
Can somebody explain it to me?

Comment: Does your pc have bluetooth? Is it turned on? Is bluetooth turned on on the device? Is it set to discoverable on device?

Comment: yes, i have bluetooth 4.0 usb adapter and it's turned on. when i try to find my device via iPhone it works, but windows can't

Comment: So this is not related with programming. Have you tried other tools for example [this](http://www.windows7download.com/win7-widcomm-bluetooth/amphfxne.html)?

Comment: Regarding your "bluetooth 4.0 usb adapter". As far I know, a standard Bluetooth dongle is no good.  It must be the special "CC2540 USBDongle" which appears as a serial port and not as a Bluetooth USB device.

Comment: Any updates? Actually I am trying to do same.

Comment: @Sweety. I've found the solution. You have to buy Bluegiga dongle. They have an api to work with ble devices in c and java. but it can be easily ported to c#, etc. [link](http://www.bluegiga.com/BLED112_Bluetooth_smart_dongle)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bluetooth Low Energy API for Windows 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401435/bluetooth-low-energy-api-for-windows-7-0)