# Bluetooth Low Energy Java Api or C/C++ Library

Tags: java, c++, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is there any recently ported Java api or C/C++ library I can use to write a BLE standalone programs under windows XP or mac mini?

As I read in this post: "[Bluetooth Low Energy API for Windows 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401435/bluetooth-low-energy-api-for-windows)" such api is only available for windows 8.

Does somebody know any link that could be useful to start programming BLE applications under windows 8?

Thanks in advance,
Joel

Answer (score 0):

For the sample code refer to the "Example" for some of the functions listed in the link given below
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh450825(v=vs.85).aspx

hope that helps to some extent