# Java windows 7 API to connect BLE device

Tags: windows, api, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm currently looking for a Java API on windows 7 to reach a Bluetooth Low energy device...I've seen that Microsoft supports Gatt on Windows 8 but I'm wondering if there is a similar project available on windows 7 ?

I've seen in a previous post [Bluetooth Low Energy API for Windows 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401435/bluetooth-low-energy-api-for-windows-7-0) that it was not available, but as BLE is quite huge topic may be thing has changed ?

thanks a lot for your answers !
Tiamat.

Comment: Have you looked at the BlueZ stack? I can't try now but works well for LE on Linux.