# How to read Bluetooth Low Energy RSSI in Java not android

Tags: java, windows, bluetooth-lowenergy, texas-instruments

I have a Bluetooth low energy USB that is based on TI CC2540, all i need to do is to scan the RSSI values from other beacons using my computer and save it in the database (Mysql,etc), is there a Java library that does this? I know how to do it in Android but i need to do it on my PC that is operating on Windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bluetooth Low Energy API for Windows 7.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401435/bluetooth-low-energy-api-for-windows-7-0)

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on Linux platform with similar application.

First C-program who looks for BLE enabled devices via terminal. Make sure that you've installed bluez and btmon

```
    strcpy( command, "sudo ./btmon & hcitool lescan" );
    system(command);
```

compile and run the file from within Java and read the InputStream of console.

```
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("/beacon");
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process process = builder.start();
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

Ones you get the Stream of data you can look for RSSI values and export them to your database.

Comment: This is a Linux solution; the question is targeting Windows.

Answer (score 0):

[Bluetooth Low Energy API for Windows 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401435/bluetooth-low-energy-api-for-windows-7-0) asks a similar question. Unfortunately, the answer there seems to be that only Windows 8 (not older versions) supports BLE.

Answer (score -1):

Try this library:

https://github.com/movisens/SmartGattLib

From the ReadMe:

"SmartGattLib is a Java library that simplifies the work with Bluetooth SMART devices (a.k.a. Bluetooth Low Energy in Bluetooth 4.0). It provides all UUIDs of the adopted GATT specification and an convenient way to interpret the characteristics (e.g. Heart Rate, BatteryLevel)."

Comment: This is an android library, the question is targeting a PC